# How to replace a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, get

i need to quit the zero of the value of mes1 mes2 and mes3 if the result is 010, 011 or 012
but when i use an if and run an alert of the new var the result is undefined
this is the function:

```js
function getImpuestos() {
      $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/av/v1/vencimientos/"+$("#cuit").val()+"", function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          var fecha = result.data[i].vencimiento;
          var periodo = fecha.substr(0,7);
          var dt = new Date();
          var year = dt.getFullYear();
          var mes1 = year + "-0" + (dt.getMonth()+1);
          var mes2 = year + "-0" + (dt.getMonth()+2);
          var mes3 = year + "-0" + (dt.getMonth()+3);
          if(mes1 > 7){
            var mes1 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1);
          }else if(mes2 > 7){
            var mes2 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+2);
          }else if(mes3 > 7){
            var mes3 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+3);
          }
          if(periodo == mes1 || periodo == mes2 || periodo == mes3) {
            $(".fa-spinner").css("display", "block");
            $("#textobusqueda").css("display", "block");
            console.log(result.data[i].idImpuesto);
            alert(mes5);
            buscarImpuesto(result.data[i].idImpuesto, result.data[i].vencimiento, result.data[i].tipoOperacion, periodo);
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<label style="color:black" class="control-label">Ingresar CUIT Empresa</label>
            <input id="cuit" type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="searchCliente();">
```

Comment: You need to have all values consisting of two digits like 01, 04, 09, 10, 11?

Comment: you are alerting the variable `mes5`.... you never defined a variable with that name

Comment: the original names of the new vars is mes4, mes5, mes6

Comment: @MarcinSzwarc yes

Comment: @Augustin see the solution with `padStart` below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.padStart` instead of ifs:

```
var mes1 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, "0");
var mes2 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+2).padStart(2, "0");
var mes3 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+3).padStart(2, "0");
```

And of course change `mes5` in alert to something different.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: (dt.getMonth(...) + 1).padStart is not a function

Comment: I forgot about tostring: `var mes1 = year + "-" + (dt.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0");`

Comment: var mes1, 2 and 3 is set to year, hyphen ("-") and then you get current month, add one (or two or three) and pad string with zeros at the beginning. Padding string means to add some characters to beginning (zeros in this case) to have specified length.